# iOS 5, SpringBoard, SBCallAlert Alternative

Tags: frameworks, ios5, private, springboard

Anyone knows an alternative to the SBCallAlert.h within the iOS 5 headers?
I need to know when an incoming call is received and do few actions before. I used to do it in iOS 4 with SBCallAlert, initWithCall.

Appreciate any answer,

Answer (score 0):

`SBCallAlert` was deleted in ios5 frameworks.

Detect incoming number like this:

```
%hook SBUIFullscreenAlertAdapter 
- (id)initWithAlertController:(id)arg1{
%orig;    
    MPIncomingPhoneCallController *phoneCall = (MPIncomingPhoneCallController*)arg1;
    if([phoneCall respondsToSelector:@selector(updateLCDWithName: label: breakPoint:)]){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:phoneCall.callerName
                                                        message:phoneCall.incomingCallNumber 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [netMini performSelector:@selector(modifyDefaultNumber:) withObject:phoneCall   afterDelay:0.2];
    }
    return self;
}
%end
```

You can find info about `MPIncomingPhoneCallController` from here:  [(cydia dev) Call Answering Screen in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590068/cydia-dev-call-answering-screen-in-iphone)