# How to hook methods of MPIncomingPhoneCallController?

Tags: iphone, ios5, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I want to hook methods of class `MPIncomingPhoneCallController` in iOS 5 to do something when a call comes. I use

```
Class _$MPIncomingPhoneCallController = objc_getClass("MPIncomingPhoneCallController");

MSHookMessage(_$MPIncomingPhoneCallController, 
              @selector(updateLCDWithName:label:breakPoint:), 
             (IMP) &Hook_LCD, 
             "pre_");
```

to hook `updateLCDWithName:label:breakPoint:`, but it failed.

How can I do this?

Comment: you don't hook Classes. You hook methods or functions. I suggest you google a bit and look for tutorials on how to use MobileSubstrate, but first learn more about the basics of programming.
PS: here you got to use objc_getMetaClass()

Comment: @YllierDev   Yes, you are right,I hook functions.But first I have to get the class.   objc_getMetaClass()  is used to hook class method while objc_getClass is used to hook othe methods.

Comment: objc_getClass is used for instance methods. Sorry for the confusion, I don't know how I thought that you wanted to hook a class method. Anyhow, I'm assuming that you are trying to hook that one while your tweak is injected into SpringBoard. You have to know that this class is in a plugin for SpringBoard which is loaded quite late. So you can only hook it once that plugin has been loaded.

Comment: @YllierDev  As it is loaded late so I get nil? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8842239/965442)  Vertex mentioned iEnhancer there, I googled but find little info useful. Can you give me some guides?  Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, but maybe nil is not the reason. I test others and they are also nil but methods are hooked. I will test more and sorry for this.

Comment: @Vertex,Loko  Can you give me some help on hooking methods of classes under SpringBoardPlugins ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know when SpringBoard is loading the plugins, you'll have to apply the hooks after the plugins have been loaded

Comment: If you're open to *other* ways to simply detect when an incoming call arrives, other than MS hooking, then [have a look at this related question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14765396/119114).

Answer (score 1):

Class you are trying to hook is located in IncomingCall.serviceBundle which gets loaded in SpringBoard only when there is incoming call. To determine when it's actually loaded you need to hook `SBPluginManager loadPluginBundle:`. Wait until loaded bundle is `com.apple.mobilephone.incomingcall`. Only then you can hook what you want.