# Hide a phone call iOS 6 and 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak

I have seen this question and answer a few weeks ago and I tested it and it's answer works great:

- [Hide a phone call completely in iOS (jailbreak device)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729003/hide-a-phone-call-completely-in-ios-jailbreak-device)

The author of the answer (creker) says that this can be done in iOS 6 and iOS 5 but it's more complex than iOS 7. I have tried to port it to iOS 6 but it's very hard to find the right classes and methods. Does anyone know what are the right classes and methods to hook in iOS 6 and iOS 5?