# ios call phone number without user permission

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to call a specific (xxxxxx) phone number without letting the user see the alert to confirm the call.

of course, this is for internal use and private api is welcome.

currently, I'm using:

```
let url = URL(string: "tel://xxxx")!
UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But it presents the unwanted alert.

Comment: This might help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236573/do-iphone-apps-have-permission-to-make-calls-without-user-interaction

Comment: You have to use coreTelephony for that with it's private API's.

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729003/hide-a-phone-call-completely-in-ios-jailbreak-device/22897769#22897769