# Get incoming call number on iOS 10

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, cydia

I am trying to use private APIs to achieve this.

These are the classes I know that can help, but responses to existing questions such as these don't work -

[Disconnect or connect an iPhone call programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531941/disconnect-or-connect-an-iphone-call-programmatically)

Some of the classes have changed since MobileSubstrate crashes on iOS 10 when I hook SPPluginManager or Incomingcall.servicebundle.

Please point me to the right class/function hook for Theos development.